# Why auth component redirect to login?

Tags: php, cakephp

Why auth component redirect to login ?

I am using : https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-jwt-auth

my controller config looks like:

```
public $components = [
        'RequestHandler',
        'Auth' => [
            'authenticate', [
                'ADmad/JwtAuth.Jwt' => [
                    'parameter' => 'access_token',
                    'userModel' => 'Users',
                    'scope' => ['Users.active' => 1],
                    'fields' => [
                        'id' => 'id'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => false,
            'sessionKey' => false,
            'loginRedirect' => false,
            'redirect' => false,
            'logoutRedirect' => false,
            'checkAuthIn' => 'Controller.initialize',
        ]
    ];
```

And when i enter the restricted action it want me to redirect to unexisted login action in this controller? How can i fix this and return `403` response ?

> The action login is not defined in UsersController
>
> Error: Create UsersController::login() in file:
>   src\Controller\UsersController.php.

Comment: i had to add this line to my .htaccess file `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]`